I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project, I have to add auto indexing (sublist) to its various sections and subsections
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project, it has section of add checklist, inside this there are 2 options

add subchecklist
add policy

Again inside policy there is option of add compliance, I have to add sublisting for checklist, subchecklist, policy and compliance like (1 ,1.a , 1.1 , 1.1.1 ) (2 , 2.a , 2.1 , 2.1.1) ....
How can I do it? Please tell me about the process step-by-step.
I tried but subchecklist and policy got same numbering like 1.1 and 1.1 rather than 1.a and 1.1

Could you please share your current codes? And what's the next for 1.1.1 and 2.1.1 ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
